# How can I start a service in Spring Boot when the server has started?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a service (bean) that cannot be activated before the jetty server has started.

Is there a way to achieve that easily with Spring/Spring Boot?

Regards,

Jakob

Comment: The reason btw is that the service listens to the management service /health and fails when that service isn't started yet. The service is legacy code and hard to reimplement.

Answer (score 3):

If you use JavaConfig (which i assume you do with Spring Boot) you can use the DependsOn annotation with the bean name of the HealthEndpoint (with the default auto configuration, the bean name of the health endpoint is healthEndpoint):

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("healthEndpoint")
public YourService yourService() {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this doesn't seem to be doing any difference. The problem is that the service calls http://localhost:<management port>/health to validate the the server is up and running. The HealthEndPoint seems to be initialized some time before the server is actually started.

Comment: I guess the answer might me to use AOP for this. Anybody that has any experience with that approach for a similar case?

Comment: You could try it with the bean jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory. I don't see, how AOP could help you here.

Answer (score 3):

You could have your service bean implement [SmartLifecycle](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html) and set it to auto-start. It will be started only once the application context has been refreshed.